# Ionic 3 - I want a modal screen not full size

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, css-position, modalviewcontroller

I need a modal page with no full size (80% width, <60% height, centered) to select some items, like an alert control.
How to implement the CSS for this case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Initialize modal with `cssClass`

```
 let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(CustomSelectPage, {data: data}, {cssClass: 'select-modal' });
```

Then add CSS to the class in `app.scss`

```
.select-modal {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
   padding: 20% 10%  !important;
}
```

Change the numbers according to your design.

Comment: Great, worked fine. There is a way to round corners, like [link](https://i.pinimg.com/236x/a9/7b/5c/a97b5c103c945d0cb0aba5fed9cb9f11.jpg) ?

Comment: I wanted that rounded effect as well.  I did the following:
`.text-properties-modal {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
 padding: 20% 10% !important;
 .modal-wrapper {
  border-radius: 20px;
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

> put this code only in your component css file
>
> ```
> ::ng-deep .sc-ion-modal-md-h {
> --width: 90%;
> --height: 70%;
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

in TS file:

```
  async MyModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: MyModalPage,
      backdropDismiss: true,
      cssClass: 'my-modal',
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

in SCSS file:

```
.my-modal {
  --width: 70%;
  --height: 35%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign a class to modal (ionic-4 & ionic-5)

```
this.modalCtrl
  .create({
    component: ReportEventComponent,
    cssClass: 'add-contact-modal'
  })
  .then(modalEl => {
    modalEl.present();
    return modalEl.onDidDismiss();
});
```

put your css code into global.css file

```
ion-modal.add-contact-modal {
  --height: 85%;
  --width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Ionic 6 and it worked here.
Add in global.scss:

```
.premio-modal{
  // background-color: red;
  .modal-wrapper{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    /* padding: 20% 10% !important; */
    width: 70%;
    height: 75%;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}
```

In component:

```
async showModal(){
        const modal = await this.modalController.create({
          component: YourComponent,
          cssClass: 'premio-modal',
          backdropDismiss: true,
          
        });
        modal.onDidDismiss().then(
          (m: any) => {
          }
        );
        return await modal.present();
      }
```