# Ionic 3 can't change size of modal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to change a modal size not to be full screen. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185664/ionic-3-i-want-a-modal-screen-not-full-size). It doesn't work. The modal is still full size. This is how i open the modal:

```
private presentModal() {
 let profileModal = this.modalController.create(AddToCustomListModal, {cssClass: 'my-modal'});
 profileModal.present();
}
```

My modal page:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-to-custom-list',
  templateUrl: 'add-to-custom-list.html',
})
export class AddToCustomListModal {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

}
```

The html of my modal, just a generic example of an ion select:

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Period</ion-label>
      <ion-select>
        <ion-option value="7day">7 days</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="overall" selected="true">overall</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>

</ion-content>
```

And my global app.scss file:

```
.my-modal {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    padding: 20% 10%  !important;
}
```

I also tried putting the css code inside the page's scss file but with no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
private presentModal() {
 let profileModal = this.modalController.create(AddToCustomListModal, null, {cssClass: 'my-modal'});
 profileModal.present();
}
```

`ModalController.create` accepts 3 arguments.

1. component
2. data
3. opts

If you need to set `cssClass` it should be sent as **opts**.